# How to improve PHPUnit tests run? By freezing code somehow, for example

Tags: docker, testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I am working with a code with a lot of tests (i suppose). There are about 6000 tests. Cost of running that tests is 1m 30sec. You may think that it is nothing, but during tests execution you can do nothing with Your code, because PHPUnit doesn't seem to freeze tested and test's code (which is understandable) and if You change anything during tests execution some tests may fail. I have whole project on docker container with shared folders set by `-v` parameter.

I have imagined sth like that:

1) In PHPStorm runs tests;

2) Stops sharing folder between docker and host during test execution to preserve code state at the moment when tests started;

3) Complete tests execution, show any errors if present, bring back folder sharing.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I would simply build a new image with your code copied into the image during docker build and run the tests inside a container based on that image. This way you'd have an isolated unit test environment, you would not bind your host folder into the container.

Comment: you can run tests into `Docker` with `PhpStorm`. But i don`t know how to unmount volume and do not brake anything. May be `OPCache` will help you?

Comment: @Mark Can i automate this process and connect it to PHPStorm somehow ?

Comment: You can definitely automate it, you can [use docker-compose and docker-compose override](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to share configuration between development and production/staging/testing and build your image with one command. 
You can of course further sophisticate this with shell scripts or automation software if you like.